# Convert from full path to relative path

Tags: ant, path, relative-path, absolute-path, build-tools

In ant, how can I convert the file path of a file to a relative path? Here is what I have so far that still keeps the full path for the file

```
<path id="build.classpath">
<fileset dir="../../lib">
<include name="*.jar"/>
</fileset>
</path>
<pathconvert property="mf.classpath" pathsep=" " refid="build.classpath">
<map from="${build.classpath}" to="lib/"/>
</pathconvert>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to the problem is as follows

```
<path id="build.classpath">
<fileset dir="../../lib">
  <include name="*.jar"/>
</fileset>
</path>
<pathconvert property="mf.classpath" refid="build.classpath" pathsep=" ">
<chainedmapper>
<flattenmapper/>
<globmapper from="*" to="../lib/*"/>
</chainedmapper>
</pathconvert>
```

Use the chain mapper to chain different mappings together, and flatten the string to just the file name. Then glob all the files and append the relative path to the front.